# Attach javascript function to rich:dataScroller

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I have a **rich:datatable** in which every row contains a **selectOneCheckbox**. A javascript function is bound to checkboxes and deselects the current selected checkbox when another one is checked (so, only a checkbox per time can be checked within a page). The datatable uses a rich:datascroller for scrolling through result pages.

How can I deselect a row before scrolling to another page?
Example: I am at page 1 and select the checkbox for row1, then I press "3" on the scrollbar: the selection for row1 remains, but I would like to remove it before showing page 3**strong text**.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

The [rich:datascroller tag](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/dataTableScroller.jsf?tab=info&cid=852706) has an "onclick" attribute where you can make a call to your js function:

```
<rich:datascroller id="myscroller"  onclick="unselectCombos()" />
```

I think this will work.

Comment: I don't know why but onclick didn't work. I used onbegin indeed.. Thanks anyway!